# Command line issue with ogr2ogr and WKT

Tags: windows, command-line, gdal, wkt, ogr2ogr

I want to clip a shapefile with ogr2ogr using a POLYGON defined as wkt.

According to the documentation it should be possible to use WKT as clipsrc [1]

But I cant get the syntax right, I the following there is some simplified commands, that gives me the error.

I have tried the following, all it does is resulting in

```
FAILURE: Invalid geometry. Must be a valid POLYGON or MULTIPOLYGON WKT
```

Commands I have used:

```
ogr2ogr -clipsrc "POLYGON ^(^(10 0, 2 10, 34 0^)^)"

ogr2ogr -clipsrc POLYGON ^(^(10 0, 2 10, 34 0^)^)

ogr2ogr -clipsrc "POLYGON ((10 0, 2 10, 34 0))"

ogr2ogr -clipsrc POLYGON ((10 0, 2 10, 34 0))
```

[1] http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [Well-known text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text) to get an overview of the markup. Your last example is the closest resemblance to WKT. Closing the linear ring and enclosing the string with quotes, try:

```
ogr2ogr -clipsrc "POLYGON ((10 0, 2 10, 34 0, 10 0))"
```

which describes the shape of a triangle that looks like this:

[image: triangle]